# Typing of overridden method, called by inherited method, in TypeScript (Bug?)

Tags: typescript, inheritance, methods, overriding

I stumbled accross the following scenario recently:

```
class A {
  public m1(x: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    return this.m2(x);
  }
  protected m2(x: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    return x;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  protected m2(x: string[]): string { // no compiler warning
    return x.join(',');
  }
}
const b = new B();
console.log(b.m1(['a', 'b', 'c'])); // ok
console.log(b.m1('d')); // runtime error
```

Is this a bug in the TypeScript typing system or intentional? If the latter, how can I change the typing so that the compiler will recognize the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, methods are [bivariant](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) and function properties contravariant with [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types). Note their different syntax:

```
class MyClass {
  public fn(a: string): string { ... } // this is a method
  public fn = (a: string): string => { ... } // this is a function as property
}
```

To enable stricter typing for `m2`, you need to have `--strictFunctionTypes` enabled (default with `strict`) and use a function property:

```
protected m2 = (x: string | string[]): string | string[] => {
  return x;
}
```

Now, `m2` will error properly and you will need to distinguish between `string` and `string[]`:

```
protected m2 = (x: string | string[]): string => { 
  return Array.isArray(x) ? x.join(',') : `${x},`;
}
```

[Live code example on Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=11&pln=14&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4FcBGICWw0AtgIwAUAHgFzQQAuATngHYDm0APrYy6wNoBdAJQ16TNp27j%20AxCjQKGAUzqYGzaHQAWeCADoiAJkpCA3PNQBfCxgYB7OkuCOAJsUPQAvNEqieErjFeQREpXkkgtkEvAD45BUUVNQ0KcwVra1BIGAAhaCUKR2YXGHhkBXR7R2clNyMvH2owqOE-aVjEaAB6LvyGewYYZjsAd2hIaBclCDxlFxtE1XVoCj0AKzsWMgByABptsxtrGx7u3oBlOxBMOjw7DQKwInQQJRPe1EqHJ1d3Bt9muxAv4ZKFIuxPHEENB3gllEsNLB%20mAAJ56XRIhiokzQAD8K3Wm2YO32QmgNAABgASBAUSy7ClpNCnKxIaxAA)

Related: [What are covariance and contravariance?](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance)

Related: [JS class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I never would have thought there is a difference between methods and function properties with regard to variance. Also, as your first related link states, "In TypeScript, argument types are bivariant (both covariant and contravariant), _which is unsound_".

Comment: Yes, methods are considered unsound. This has been a conscious decision by the core developers to make built-in methods, like from `Array`, not more complicated as necessary for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected an behaviour. In typescript, you override a method to funnel down the specificity of the method instead of widening it as in other languages.

As for the explanation...

```
class A {
  public m1(x: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    /**
     * Here variable 'x' is of type string | string[], which perfectly overlaps 
     * with the arguments for the method m2. So you won't get a compile-time error
     */
    return this.m2(x);
  }
  protected m2(x: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    return x;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  /**
   * Here method m2 is overridden by a method which accepts a string[], which
   * is covered by the parent's method, and hence no compile-time error. If
   * you made the argument type to 'string', it would still be accepted.
   */
  protected m2(x: string[]): string { // no compiler warning
    return x.join(',');
  }
}
const b = new B();
console.log(b.m1(['a', 'b', 'c'])); // ok
/**
 * Here you are passing the type you have specified method m1 will take. So there is no issue here as well
 */
console.log(b.m1('d')); // runtime error
```

Everything said, this is a logical-error, rather than a bug.

Comment: Thanks. But in my view, `B.m2` should not be allowed this way in accordance with OOP inheritance, because an instance of `B` cannot do something (namely, accept a `string` for `m2`) that an instance of the parent class `A` can. Note that when I would call `b.m2("somestring")`, still `B.m2` is invoked, leading to an error, not `A.m2` (which might be reasonable).